# Ant giving _JAVA OPTIONS message

Tags: java, ant

I have installed Apache Ant 1.8 on Windows 8.1.

When I am running the `ant` command on console, it is showing following message on screen:
**`Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true`**

I am not able to find the reason of this message.

Attaching screen shot for your reference.
[image]

Please provide me your comments on this. Also will it impact on the working of `ant`?

**Please ignore the error about `build.xml` and '`tools.jar`.**

Comment: The error says you don't have the build.xml in your current fodder (C:\Users\ap002). Check to see whether you are in the right place, and if you missed, create a build.xml that ant can run.

Comment: Just to make sure I understood what you're really asking: you ask for the cause of the message, not why your build.xml is not found, right?

Comment: its not about the build.xml. I am asking about the first message: Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true

Comment: Guyz my question is not at all about build.xml. I am asking about the "Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true" message shown on console. Will it impact the working of `ant`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> When I am running the ant command on console, it is showing following
>   message on screen: Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS:
>   -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true
>
> I am not able to find the reason of this message.

`_JAVA_OPTIONS` is a special environment variable. It will be picked up by JVM. You are setting `java.net.preferIPv4Stack` to true means, disabling IPV6.

```
export _JAVA_OPTIONS=-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true
```

You can achive the same using

```
System.setProperty("java.net.preferIPv4Stack" , "true");
```

through the code level in the application.

> **IPv6-Related System Properties**
>
> On dual stack machines, system properties are provided for setting the
>   preferred protocol stackâ€”IPv4 or IPv6â€”as well as the preferred
>   address family typesâ€”inet4 or inet6.
>
> IPv6 stack is preferred by default, since on a dual-stack machine IPv6
>   socket can talk to both IPv4 and IPv6 peers.
>
> This setting can be changed through the
>   `java.net.preferIPv4Stack=<true|false>` system property.
>
> By default, we would prefer IPv4 addresses over IPv6 addresses, i.e.,
>   when querying the name service (e.g., DNS service), we would return
>   Ipv4 addresses ahead of IPv6 addresses.

Check here for about [Networking IPv6 User Guide for JDK/JRE 5.0](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/net/ipv6_guide/).

BTW, That's not responsible for your error there. From your error message, there is no `build.xml` file in the directory, it seems.

Comment: I have just run the ant command to check. I know that build.xml is missing. I am asking about "Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true" message.

Comment: @SachinMhetre : Yes, I Updated the answer with explanation.

Comment: @SachinMhetre : You can to it from command line, or adding this to bash_profile, or in the build.xml

Comment: Do I have to run exactly same command through cmd? Because when I tried through CMD, it is not able to get `System.property` command

Comment: @SachinMhetre : You can't execute `System.setProperty("java.net.preferIPv4Stack" , "true");` through CMD. You can this in the coding level in the application.

Comment: 'System.setProperty' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file. Should I set some environment path for this?

Comment: Thanks a lot friend!! `set _JAVA_OPTIONS=-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true` worked for me. Your answer helped me a lot.

Comment: @SachinMhetre : You are welcome, Yes, you can set any JVM properties with `_JAVA_OPTIONS`, I set the heap size using `_JAVA_OPTIONS="-Xmx12G"`